# How do I Change the Alignment of Toolbar Child Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have a toolbar and I want to add an `ImageView` to its layout in xml. I want it to align right, instead of the default align left.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html):

> The application may add arbitrary child views to the Toolbar. They will appear at this position within the layout. If a child view's Toolbar.LayoutParams indicates a Gravity value of CENTER_HORIZONTAL the view will attempt to center within the available space remaining in the Toolbar after all other elements have been measured.

But I can't set the gravity on anything.

#### My Layout

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    style="@style/ToolbarStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bluetoothState"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bluetooth_status_white"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_bluetooth_status"
        android:padding="8dp"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image: Default Alignment]

Comment: This seems like it'll be really confusing given that actions also appear in the right side of the Toolbar.

Comment: why don't you re-arrange them then, after all the new views are placed in the middle of your toolbar or in between icon and menu

Comment: @ianhanniballake this is a good point. My current imaginings see the ImageView becoming an ImageButton and acting similarly to a menu button. It might even make sense to simply use a menu and showAsAction="always". I'll have to research and see if there is some way I can use a `level-list` drawable with a menu item.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`android:layout_gravity="right"` is the answer. Which the documentation the question links too even suggests. (well it mentions gravity, but not in the particular xml attribute way needed)

Anyway, the issue was Android Studio doesn't really suggest attributes for custom views. This includes `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. The *Design* tab won't list layout_gravity as an attribute and it won't auto complete it if you type it on the text tab.

Full example code below..

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    style="@style/ToolbarStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bluetoothState"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bluetooth_status_white"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_bluetooth_status"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```